# Проблема с ToolBar - IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar

Tags: java, android

Когда комментирую эти строки эти строки

```
//toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

приложение нормально работает без ошибок
А как только убираю комментарии - КРАХ!!! "Unfortunately, appname has stopped".

**Ошибка:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

**Стили:**

```
<style name="AppTheme.With" parent="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/titleBarColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/actionBarColor</item>\
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**Манифест:**

```
<activity android:name=".Second"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.With"/>
```

**Вопрос:** Что не так?

Comment: Укажите активити в которой, пытаетесь установить toolbar, скорей всего в этом ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего вам поможет замена вашей текущей родительской темы

> Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light

на

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

Answer (score 1):

C `ToolBar` используйте `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`
Базовый стиль для ToolBar в качестве ActionBar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```